# Keeping all the JavaScript in the bottom of my page using Response.Filter in .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, filter

I have loaded some external JavaScript and some inline JavaScript to View page in my MVC project. I have heard about Response filter to move these scripts to the end of the page after content loaded but I have not exact knowledge about this.

How can I achieve this in my whole project?

Answer (score 0):

I would use build tasks (either using Grunt or Gulp) to combine and minify your scripts as static content and to rewrite your HTML to include CSS and JS resources where you want them in your page.

You could use a Gulp task such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify to combine and minify and then https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref

The whole task would look something like this:

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    var assets = useref.assets();

    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

In addition to minifying and combining assets, it allows you to define which parts of your HTML you want to target for the output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- build:css css/combined.css -->
    <link href="css/one.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/two.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- build:js scripts/combined.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/one.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/two.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

And rewrite it into this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/combined.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts/combined.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not want to minify it but I would like to push all of the JavaScript blocks to be rendered in the footer of the page, after all the content.